# Different notations for times variable in Haug's book

Tags: option-pricing, asian-option, notation

I am reading the book by Haug, 2007 on the pages 186-188 one can find the Turnbull and Wakeman approximation for arithmetic avarage rate option.

> The approximation adjusts the mean and variance so that they are
> consistent with the exact moments of the arithmetic average. The
> adjusted mean, $b_a$ and variance, $\sigma_a$, are then used as input
> in the generalized BSM formula: $$ c \approx S e^{(b_a - r)T}N(d_1)-K
>  e^{-rT}N(d_2), $$ $$ p \approx K e^{-rT}N(d_2) - S e^{(b_a -
>  r)T}N(d_1), $$ $$ d_1 =
>  \frac{\ln(S/K)+(b_a+\sigma^2_a/2)T}{\sigma_a\sqrt{T}}, \quad d_2 = d_1
>  - \sigma_a\sqrt{T}. $$ The volatility and cost-of-carry of the average are given:  $$ \sigma_a = \sqrt{\frac{\ln(M_2)}{T}-2b_a}, \quad
>  b_a = \frac{\ln(M_1)}{T},$$ where  $$ M_1 =
>  \frac{e^{bT}-e^{bt_1}}{b(T-t_1)}, $$ $$ M_2 =
>  \frac{2e^{(2b+\sigma^2)T}}{(b+\sigma^2)(2b+\sigma^2)(T-t_1)^2} +
>  \frac{2e^{(2b+\sigma^2)t_1}}{b(T-t_1)^2}\left(\frac{1}{2b+\sigma^2} -
>  \frac{e^{b(T-t_1)}}{b+\sigma^2}\right), $$ if $b = 0$, then $$M_1=1$$
> and $$ M_2 = \frac{2e^{\sigma^2 T}-2e^{\sigma^2
>  t_1}(1+\sigma^2(T-t_1))}{\sigma^4(T-t_1)^2}, $$ where $t_1$ - is the time to the beginning of the average period.
>
> Extension to hold for options on futures.
>
> If the option is into the average period, the strike price must be
> replaced by $\hat{K}$, and option value must be multiplied by  $T_2/T$, where $$ \hat{K} = \frac{T_2}{T} K - \frac{\tau}{T} S_{ave}, $$ where $\tau=T_2-T$ - is the reminding time in the average period, $T_2$ -- original time in average period in years, constant over life
> of options.
>
> If we are into the average period,  $\tau>0$ and $\frac{T_2}{T} K -
>  \frac{\tau}{T} S_{ave}<0$, then a call option will for certain be
> exercised and is equal to the expected value of the average at
> maturity minus the strike price $$ e^{-rT}(\mathbb{E}(S_{ave})-K),$$
> where the expected average at maturity is equal to
> $$\mathbb{E}(S_{ave})=S_{ave}\frac{T_2-T}{T_2} + S \cdot M_1
>  \frac{T}{T_2}. $$

In the quote above one can see four different notations for times: $t_ 1$, $\tau$, $T_ 2$ and $T$. $T$ is standard notation, while the $t_ 1$, $\tau$, and $T_ 2$ are not.

**Question.** Could some one explain what does mean  $\tau$, $T_ 2$ and $t_1$ with a visualisation for these notationds on a timeline?

$t_1$ - the time to the beginning of the average period.

$\tau$ - the reminding time in the average period.

$T_2$ - original time in average period in years, constant over life
of options.

$T$ - time to maturity in years of options.

My attempt in days is:

[image]

Ref. Espen G. Haug. The Complete Guide To Option Pricing Formulas. McGraw Hill, 2007

Comment: I usually find that book good but here I cannot help thinking that this part is a complete mess and it should have been the author's duty to provide that timeline. It also does not help that he changed the notation between the 1st and 2nd edition and probably fixed some errors (who knows?). Finally he introduced a typo "reminding" time into the 2nd edition. No Kudos Dr. Haug.

Comment: In the Haug's book I have found some typo too in tables with calculation's results. My timeline is provided.

Comment: @KurtG., do you have both editions?

Comment: Regrettably yes. Forget the first one. It is not any better. My recommendation is to implement the formula and test it against other ways to value that option. Monte Carlo simulation in the worst case, or take a small averaging window where you can compare with plain vanilla option in Black-Scholes. I do not think the Turnbull-Wakeman formula is widely used in practice. Why should we spend time on the mess that Haug started?